# Google map API not loaded full when called second time

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I am using Google map that is displayed as a dialog box, this control is added dynamically to a page multiple time. Now when i open the map for first time it displays fine and i am able to select a location and use it etc. But when i open the map again, the map is displayed partially at the left top corner. Any help on why this would occur

```
function Initialize(id) {
    if (!map) {
        var Utrecht = new google.maps.LatLng(52.071065, 5.111389);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: Utrecht
            , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            , draggableCursor: 'crosshair'
            , streetViewControl: false
            , panControl: false
        };
        var mapDiv = $('#ContentPlaceHolderBody_mapsCtrl' + id + '_map' + id);
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv[0], myOptions);
    }
    else
    {
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        position = event.latLng;
        CallServer('loc:' + event.latLng.toUrlValue(), "");
    });
}
```

EDIT - This is how i am showing the dialog with map

```
 $('#ContentPlaceHolderBody_mapsCtrl' + id + '_mapDiv' + id).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: window
            },
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            open: Initialize(id)

        });
    $('#ContentPlaceHolderBody_mapsCtrl' + id + '_mapDiv' + id).dialog("open");
    AutoResizeFrame();
```

Comment: the implementation of the dialog-box would be interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `google.maps.event.clearListeners(window, 'resize');` before closing the dialog and in the else part of the Initialize function worked now i am getting map displayed in full all time.

```
else
{
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map);
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(window, 'resize');
}
```